# Using Indexable Properties with i4o library

Tags: c#, .net, indexing, clr

I want to define some properties on a class using the [Indexable()] attribute in order to use the class with the i4o library (http://www.codeplex.com/i4o) but when I try and compile the code Visual Studio says it cannot find the Namespace for Indexable.

Is this part of the CLR and which namespace/library do I need to get this to compile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Indexable()] isn't an attribute included in the .NET Framework. It was removed from i4o in favor of other approaches. See [this blog post](http://staxmanade.blogspot.com/2008/12/i4o-indexspecification-for.html) for details on how to use it.

Answer (score 4):

Its not a part of the standard framework.  You're going to need to identify what assembly contains this IndexableAttribute and reference it in your project.

Where is it located?  I don't know.  Who told you you needed to do this?  Is it i4o?  If so, its probably within one of the binaries that comes with the i4o project.